# Subclass Constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am having trouble working with subclasses in C++. I have a class for a Polygon and a subclass that is a Triangle. I would like to be able to declare a Polygon by passing a vector of Point* (which is a custom class) and a Triangle by passing three Point*s.

It is my understanding that the Triangle class constructor should call the constructor of the Polygon class.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Polygon
{
public:
    vector<Point*> pts;
    Polygon(vector<Point*> aPts) : pts(aPts) {};
};
class Triangle : public Polygon
{
public:
    Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) 
    {
        vector<Point*> APts;
        APts.push_back(A); APts.push_back(B); APts.push_back(C);
        Polygon(APts);
    }
};
```

However, on the opening bracket of the Triangle constructor I get the error:

```
error: no matching function call to 'Polygon::Polygon()'
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: You can call parent class's constructor only from initializer's list

Comment: Why vector of pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class has to be initialised before the derived class's constructor body; if the constructor needs arguments, then these must be supplied in the initialiser list:

```
Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) :
    Polygon({A,B,C})
{}
```

Note that this uses C++11 syntax to create a temporary vector; if you're stuck in the past then it's a bit more complicated:

```
static std::vector<Point*> make_points(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) {
    std::vector<Point*> points;
    points.push_back(A);
    points.push_back(B);
    points.push_back(C);
}

Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) :
    Polygon(make_points(A,B,C))
{}
```

or it might be easier (but potentially more error-prone) to give the base class a default constructor, and then populate the vector in the derived class constructor:

```
// In Polygon
Polygon() {} // constructed with no points
// pts must be "public" or "protected"

// In Triangle
Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) {
    pts.push_back(A);
    pts.push_back(B);
    pts.push_back(C);
}
```

Comment: That's a clever use of the C++ initializer list. Subtle, but smart ;)

Comment: This gives me "Error: Expected primary expression before '{' token".

Comment: @DanBrenner: That's because your compiler is stuck in the past; you probably need to tell it to build C++11. From the error, I'm guessing it's GCC, so you'll need the command line option `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` for older compiler versions).

Comment: @iammilind: You mean to avoid creating and moving a temporary vector? The move should be elided, even if the cost is worth worrying about.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, your answer is correct, I misunderstood. Comment removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an `addPoint()` function in your `Polygon` class

```
class Polygon{
  public:
    vector<Point*> pts;
    Polygon(){}/// < The default constructor
    Polygon(vector<Point*> aPts) : pts(aPts) {}
    void addPoint(Point* p){
        pts.push_back(p);
    }
};
class Triangle : public Polygon{
public:
    Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C){// calls the default constructor
        addPoint(A);
        addPoint(B);
        addPoint(C);
    }
};
```

additionally, A `Point` can be **copied by value** most of the time. I don't know why you are passing it by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to call the default constructor of `Polygon` class, but since you have your own constructor in place the default empty constructor doesn't exist anymore. Hence, you will have to call the `Polygon's` constructor with proper arguments or define an empty constructor.

Also, you can't the `Polygon's` constructor with the arguments like that, this has to be done in initialization list of `Triangle` class constructor. It is such in order to make sure that the members of `base` are properly initialized before `derived` class object is created.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Polygon` class, you define a constructor taking an argument, `vector`. In this case the compiler will not generate a default constructor, so you *have* to pass a `Polygon` constructor a parameter.

In `Triangle`, you define a constructor taking three parameters, but you don't call a constructor of `Polygon`. The compiler tries to find a default constructor - one with no parameters - but can't find one, so emits an error.

You cannot call the `Polygon` constructor at the end of the `Triangle` constructor like you have written. `Polygon` ctor must be executed before the `Triangle ctor.

Try adding a ctor to `Polygon` that takes the three `Point`s directly instead of in a `vector`, like this

```
class Polygon
{
public:
    vector<Point*> pts;
    Polygon(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) {
        pts.push_back(A);
        pts.push_back(B);
        pts.push_back(C);
    }
};
class Triangle : public Polygon
{
public:
    Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) : Polygon(A, B, C)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: What will happen to square ?

Comment: `square` isn't mentioned in the OP :P This isn't a generic solution, but serves to answer the problem as described which is about calling base class constructors. There's plenty of problems with the code that should be fixed, but a code review is out of scope here. Strangely the accepted answer uses C++11, yet the questions isn't tagged `C++11`, so there's a bit of guesswork in what the OP is looking for in their question.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor of the base class should be called from the subclass's constructor's initializer list. That's what causing compiler error in your code. Also the below syntax is valid, but it just creates a temporary object of `Polygon` and destoys it:

```
Polygon(APts);
```

From design point of view, by copying vectors by value you are doing expensive operations.
Just don't do it. Have a no argument constructor and then later populate the constructor.

```
class Polygon
{
public:
    vector<Point*> pts;  // can be made protected as well
    Polygon() {};
};
class Triangle : public Polygon
{
public:
    Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) 
    {
        pts.push_back(A); pts.push_back(B); pts.push_back(C);
    }
};
```

If you have support for C++11, then the same code can be wrote more elegantly.

```
class Polygon {
protected:
  vector<Point*> pts; 
public:
  Polygon(std::initializer_list<Point*>& v) : pts(v) {}
};

class Triangle : public Polygon {
public:
  Triangle (Point* p1, Point* p2, Point* p3) :
  Polygon({p1, p2, p3}) {}
};

class Square : public Polygon {
public:
  Square (Point* p1, Point* p2, Point* p3, Point* p4) :
  Polygon({p1, p2, p3, p4}) {}
};
```

Usage:

```
Triangle t({x, y, z});
Square s({w, x, y, z});
```

Comment: What about `Triangle s({w, x, y, z});` ?

Comment: @NeelBasu, yes that's a very good point. I think we have to have the constructor in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the Polygon constructor as a part of your initializer list, which means that you need to build a function that initializes your vector;

```
class Triangle : public Polygon
{
    // static method, not part of the object being constructed.
    static vector<Point*> BuildVector(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) {
        vector<Point*> APts;
        APts.push_back(A); APts.push_back(B); APts.push_back(C);
        return APts;
    }

public:

    // Need to call Polygon's constructor before even entering our own;
    Triangle(Point* A, Point* B, Point* C) : Polygon(BuildVector(A, B, C))
    {
    }
};
```

Note that by pushing the pointers into a vector without copying the objects, you'll risk not doing memory handling correctly (who will free the memory?), so you may want to use some type of [**smart pointer**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), or just pass the points as references into the constructor.